# Is the median a type of mean, for some generalization of "mean"?

Tags: mean, median, types-of-averages

The concept of "mean" roams far wider than the traditional arithmetic mean; does it stretch so far as to include the median? By analogy,

$$
\text{raw data} \overset{\text{id}}{\longrightarrow} \text{raw data} \overset{\text{mean}}{\longrightarrow} \text{raw mean} \overset{\text{id}^{-1}}{\longrightarrow}  \text{arithmetic mean} \\
\text{raw data} \overset{\text{recip}}{\longrightarrow} \text{reciprocals} \overset{\text{mean}}{\longrightarrow} \text{mean reciprocal} \overset{\text{recip}^{-1}}{\longrightarrow}  \text{harmonic mean} \\
\text{raw data} \overset{\text{log}}{\longrightarrow} \text{logs} \overset{\text{mean}}{\longrightarrow} \text{mean log} \overset{\text{log}^{-1}}{\longrightarrow}  \text{geometric mean} \\
\text{raw data} \overset{\text{square}}{\longrightarrow} \text{squares} \overset{\text{mean}}{\longrightarrow} \text{mean square} \overset{\text{square}^{-1}}{\longrightarrow}  \text{root mean square} \\
\text{raw data} \overset{\text{rank}}{\longrightarrow} \text{ranks} \overset{\text{mean}}{\longrightarrow} \text{mean rank} \overset{\text{rank}^{-1}}{\longrightarrow}  \text{median} 
$$

The analogy I am drawing is to the [quasi-arithmetic mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-arithmetic_mean), given by:

$$M_f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=f^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_i) \right)$$

For comparison, when we say that the median of a five-item dataset is equal to the third item, we can see that as equivalent to ranking the data from one to five (which we might denote by a function $f$); taking the mean of the transformed data (which is three); and reading back off the value of the item of data that had rank three (a sort of $f^{-1}$).

In the examples of geometric mean, harmonic mean and RMS, $f$ was a fixed function that can be applied to any number in isolation. In contrast, either to assign a rank, or to work back from ranks to the original data (interpolating where necessary) requires knowledge of the entire data set. Moreover in definitions I have read of the quasi-arithmetic mean, $f$ is required to be continuous. Is the median ever considered as a special case of quasi-arithmetic mean, and if so how is the $f$ defined? Or is the median ever described as an instance of some other wider notion of "mean"? The quasi-arithmetic mean is certainly not the only generalization available.

Part of the issue is terminological (what does "mean" mean anyway, especially in contrast to "central tendency" or "average"?). For instance, in the literature for [fuzzy control systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_control_system), an aggregation function $F:[a,b] \times [a,b] \to [a,b]$ is an increasing function with $F(a,a)=a$ and $F(b,b)=b$; an aggregation function for which $\min(x,y) \leq F(x,y) \leq \max(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in [a,b]$ is called a "mean" (in a general sense). Such a definition is, needless to say, incredibly broad! And in this context the median is indeed referred to as a type of mean.$^{[1]}$ But I am curious whether less broad characterisations of the mean can still extend far enough to encompass the median – the so-called [generalized mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean) (which might better be described as the "power mean") and the [Lehmer mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_mean) do not, but others may. For what it's worth, [Wikipedia includes "median" in its list of "other means"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean#Other_means), but without further comment or citation.

$[1]$: Such a broad definition of mean, suitably extended for more than two inputs, seems standard in the field of fuzzy control and cropped up many times during internet searches for instances of the median being described as a median; I will cite e.g. Fodor, J. C., & Rudas, I. J. (2009), "[On Some Classes of Aggregation Functions that are Migrative](http://www.eusflat.org/proceedings/IFSA-EUSFLAT_2009/pdf/tema_0653.pdf)", *IFSA/EUSFLAT Conf.* (pp. 653-656). Incidentally, this paper notes that one of the earliest users of the term "mean" (*moyenne*) was [Cauchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augustin-Louis_Cauchy), in the *[Cours d'analyse de l'École royale polytechnique, 1ère partie; Analyse algébrique](https://archive.org/details/coursdanalysede00caucgoog)* (1821). Later contributions of [Aczél](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J%C3%A1nos_Acz%C3%A9l_%28mathematician%29), [Chisini](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscar_Chisini), [Kolmogorov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrey_Kolmogorov) and [de Finetti](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruno_de_Finetti) in developing more general concepts of "mean" than Cauchy are acknowledged in Fodor, J., and Roubens, M. (1995), "[On meaningfulness of means](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/223244558_On_meaningfulness_of_means)", *Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics*, **64**(1), 103-115.

Comment: I think arithmetic average, median and mode ore often called in general as "mean" and the word is sometimes used in ambiguous way. *How To Lie With Statistics* book uses it as an example of "lying" with statistics. (I understand your question is more general so post it as a comment.)

Comment: @Tim I have the unscientific impression that it's rare to see "mode" referred to as "mean". But there's definitely a huge nexus of confusion around the usage of "average" (which is sometimes used as a synonym for "arithmetic mean" and other times includes measures of central tendency that are not means at all) and "mean" (which in general use, rather than in the technical sense, is mostly but not exclusively used for "arithmetic mean"). Incidentally it's also a hard topic for internet searches, due to the *other* meanings of "mean"!

Comment: means (arithmetic, geometric, harmonic, powered, exponential, combinatorial, etc) are "analytic averages". Median, quantiles, tantiles are "positional averages". Ranking is quite different from log, square etc because it is the monotonic transformation of any variate to uniform variate and there is no back path to untransform.

Comment: Btw the term "generalized mean" is preoccupied http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean

Comment: @ttnphns Indeed, I was trying to avoid the exact term "generalized mean" for that reason, but didn't quite succeed. I will try to rephrase my question to avoid that.

Comment: @ttnphns It seems to me there is a "back-path to untransform", albeit one which is conditional on knowledge of the original data set. Just given the ranks, of course, no inverse transformation is possible. I agree that in this sense ranking is quite different - as I said in the question, the analogy is being stretched! But perhaps it is not an impossible stretch.

Comment: If you allow weights in calculation $\sum_i w_i x_i, \sum_i w_i = 1$, then the median could easily be regarded as a kind of mean. Similarly, but not identically, the concept of trimmed means certainly includes medians as a limiting or courtesy special case. http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0313 is one fairly recent review.

Comment: @NickCox Thank you. The trimmed mean example is particularly illuminating - that's a very good answer to my query as to whether the median is "as an instance of some other generalized notion of "mean"".

Comment: It's easy to prove the analogy cannot produce a median: for any $y$, by considering the datasets $(y-x,y,x)$ we see that the formula *must* depend on $f(y)$ (that is, $f$ cannot be constant in a neighborhood of $y$), but by considering the dataset $(y-2,y-1,y)$ we see that it *cannot* depend on $f(y)$. Something has to give--either you adopt @NickCox's idea of weights (set the middle two weights to $1/2$, all others to zero) or go in the direction of Mike Anderson's answer.

Comment: @whuber Is that ttnphns's point, that there's no *general* transformation from ranks to raw data? While clearly true, for a *given* data set it seems we can construct such a function. When we state that the median of a data set of five items is equal to the third item, in some sense that seems to be exactly what we are doing. We transform, $f$, the data to ranks 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5; the mean of these is 3; we read off the 3rd-ranked item - a sort of $f^{-1}$. Whether any commonly-used notion of mean stretches so far as to permit an $f$ depending on the data is the question really.

Comment: @Silver You are stretching the definitions (which is not necessarily a bad thing to do, but it needs to be recognized).  When you construct the function $f$ based on the data, you can no longer write "$f(x_i)$"; you must instead acknowledge its dependence on the other data by writing $f(x_i; x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n)$. What originally (in the examples given in the question) was a function of one variable thereby becomes a function of $n+1$ variables--which is a much more complicated object, leading to a qualitatively different concept of "mean."

Comment: @whuber I think that's a helpful way of summarising the nub of the problem. I will edit to incorporate it.

Comment: @NickCox I think you should consider converting your excellent comment into an answer. It would hardly require any further detail to be a self-standing answer.

Comment: You could say "generalization of the mean" for "generalized mean" I guess.

Comment: Considering data points $x_i$ then the arithmetic mean $x$ is the one that minimizes the average distance $\frac {1}{N} \sum (x_i - x)^2$ that is, with with the L2 norm. Can the median be similarly defined as the minimizing the distance as computed with the pseudo $\ell_0$ norm? Ps: sorry for answering with a question, I guess this could be a starting point

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's *one* way that you might regard a median as a "general sort of mean" -- first, carefully define your ordinary arithmetic mean in terms of order statistics:

$$\bar{x} = \sum_i w_i x_{(i)},\qquad w_i=\frac{_1}{^n}\,.$$

Then by replacing that ordinary average of order statistics with some other weight function, we get a  notion of "generalized mean" that accounts for order.

In that case, a host of potential measures of center become "generalized sorts of means". In the case of the median, for odd $n$, $w_{(n+1)/2}=1$ and all others are 0, and for even $n$, $w_{\frac{n}{2}}=w_{\frac{n}{2}+1}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Similarly, if we look at [M-estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-estimator), location estimates might also be thought of as a generalization of the arithmetic mean (where for the mean, $\rho$ is quadratic, $\psi$ is linear, or the weight-function is flat), and the median falls also into this class of generalizations. This is a somewhat different generalization than the previous one.

There are a variety of other ways we might extend the notion of 'mean' that could include median.

Comment: This is very nice. Closely related to this answer, and which is discussed in the papers cited in the question: the [ordered weighted average, or OWA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_weighted_averaging_aggregation_operator)

Answer (score 13):

If you think of the mean as the point minimizing the quadratic loss function SSE, then the median is the point minimizing the linear loss function MAD, and the mode is the point minimizing some 0-1 loss function.  No transformations required.

So the median is an example of a [Fréchet mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_mean).

Comment: @Mike Anderson: Well, this shows that the media is a Frechet mean (see the wikipedia article): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_mean

Comment: @Kjetil Excellent! The fact that the median is an example of a Fréchet mean is exactly an answer to my question "is the median ever described as an instance of some other wider notion of "mean"?" And +1 to Mike Anderson. I hope this information is edited into the answer.

Comment: I've added @Kjetil's comment to the answer so that it will show up in a site search for "Frechet mean". Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 5):

The question invites us to characterize the concept of "mean" in a sufficiently broad sense to encompass all the usual means--power means, $L^p$ means, medians, trimmed means--but not so broadly that it becomes almost useless for data analysis.  This reply discusses some of the axiomatic properties that any reasonably useful definition of "mean" should have.

---

#### Basic Axioms

A usefully broad definition of "mean" for the purpose of data analysis would be any sequence of well-defined, deterministic functions $f_n:A^n\to A$ for $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ and $n=1, 2, \ldots$ such that

(1) $\newcommand{\x}{\mathrm{x}} \newcommand{\min}{\text{min}}\min (\x)\le f_n(\x)\le \max(\x)$ for all $\x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)\in A^n$ (a mean lies between the extremes),

(2) $f_n$ is invariant under permutations of its arguments (means do not care about the order of the data), and

(3) each $f_n$ is nondecreasing in each of its arguments (as the numbers increase, their mean cannot decrease).

We *must* allow for $A$ to be a proper subset of real numbers (such as all positive numbers) because plenty of means, such as geometric means, are defined only on such subsets.

We might also want to add that

(1') there exists at least some $\x\in A$ for which $\min(\x)\ne f_n(\x)\ne \max(\x)$ (means are not extremes).  (We cannot require that this *always* hold.  For instance, the median of $(0,0,\ldots,0,1)$ equals $0$, which is the minimum.)

These properties seem to capture the idea behind a "mean" being some kind of "middle value" of a set of (unordered) data.

#### Consistency axioms

I am further tempted to stipulate the rather less obvious *consistency* criterion

(4.a) The range of $f_{n+1}(t, x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ as $t$ varies throughout the interval $[\min(\x), \max(\x)]$ includes $f_n(\x)$.  In other words, it is always possible to leave the mean unchanged by adjoining an appropriate value $t$ to a dataset.  In conjunction with (3), it implies that adjoining extreme values to a dataset will pull the mean towards those extremes.

If we wish to apply the concept of mean to a *distribution* or "infinite population", then one way would be to obtain it in the limit of arbitrarily large random samples.  Of course the limit might not always exist (it does not exist for the arithmetic mean when the distribution has no expectation, for instance).  Therefore I do not want to impose any additional axioms to guarantee the existence of such limits, but the following seems natural and useful:

(4.b) Whenever $A$ is bounded and $\x_n$ is a sequence of samples from a distribution $F$ supported on $A$, then the limit of $f_n(\x_n)$ almost surely exists.  This prevents the mean from forever "bouncing around" within $A$ even as sample sizes get larger and larger.

Along the same lines, we could further narrow the idea of a mean to insist that it become a better estimator of "location" as sample sizes increase:

(4.c) Whenever $A$ is bounded, then the variance of the sampling distribution of $f_n(X^{(n)})$ for a random sample $X^{(n)} = (X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n)$ of $F$ is nondecreasing in $n$.

#### Continuity axiom

We might consider asking means to vary "nicely" with the data:

(5) $f_n$ is separately continuous in each argument (a small change in the data values should not induce a sudden jump in their mean).

This requirement might eliminate some strange generalizations, but it does not rule out any well-known mean.  It will rule out some aggregation functions.

#### An invariance axiom

We can conceive of means as applying to either *interval* or *ratio* data (in Stevens' well-known sense).  We cannot demand they be invariant under shifts of location (the geometric mean is not), but we *can* require

(6) $f_n(\lambda \x) = \lambda f_n(\x)$ for all $\x \in A^n$ and all $\lambda \gt 0$ for which $\lambda \x \in A^n$.  This says only that we are free to compute $f_n$ using any units of measurement we like.

All the means mentioned in the question satisfy this axiom except for some aggregation functions.

---

#### Discussion

General aggregation functions $f_2$, as described in the question, do *not* necessarily satisfy axioms (1'), (2), (3), (5), or (6).  Whether they satisfy any consistency axioms may depend on how they are extended to $n\gt 2$.

The usual sample median enjoys all these axiomatic properties.

We could augment the consistency axioms to include

(4.d)     $f_{2n}(\x;\x) = f_n(\x)$ for all $\x \in A^n.$

This implies that when all elements of a dataset are repeated equally often, the mean does not change.  This may be too strong, though: the [Winsorized mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsorized_mean) does not have this property (except asymptotically). The purpose of Winsorizing at the $100\alpha\%$ level is to provide resistance against changes in *at least* $100\alpha\%$ of the data *at either extreme.* For instance, the 10% Winsorized mean of $(1,2,3,6)$ is the arithmetic mean of $(2,2,3,3)$, equal to $2.5$, but the 10% Winsorized mean of $(1,1,2,2,3,3,6,6)$ is $3.5$.

I do not know which of the consistency axioms (4.a), (4.b), or (4.c) would be most desirable or useful.  They appear to be independent: I don't think any two of them imply the third.

Comment: (+1) I think (1'), "means are not extremes", is an interesting point. Many otherwise natural definitions of mean happen to include the minimum and maximum as special or limiting cases: this is true of [power means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean), [Lehmer means](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_mean), [Fréchet mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_mean), [Chisini mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chisini_mean) and [Stolarsky mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolarsky_mean). Though it does seem a bit odd to refer to them as "average"!

Comment: Yes, *limiting* cases are unavoidable. But for finite datasets we might want to insist that neither the max nor the min qualify as "means."

Comment: On the other hand, not only is it true that "the usual sample median enjoys all these axiomatic properties", but so do the usual sample quantile (unless I've missed something). It also feels a bit odd to refer to e.g. the upper quartile as a "mean" (though I've seen it used as a measure of central tendency on very skewed data). If we accept all other quantiles, it no longer feels quite so perverse to admit minima and maxima. But I can certainly see it may be desirable to at least retain the right to exclude them.

Comment: I am not perturbed by the admission of quantiles into the pantheon of means.  After all, for given families of distributions, certain non-median quantiles will coincide with arithmetic means, so you could be in trouble if you tried to eliminate this possibility axiomatically. (Consider a family of lognormal distributions of constant geometric SD, for instance.) If the arithmetic mean cannot qualify as a mean, all is lost!

Comment: I like that example. I've seen another quite neat way of excluding the extremes as "mean", for $n=2$: requiring $a=f_2(a,b) \implies a=b$. That generalises easily enough to higher $n$ if we demand $f_n(x_1,...x_n)=\max(x_i)$ (or $\min$) implies all $x_i$ are equal. Foster, D.M.E. and Phillips, G.M. (1984), "[A Generalization of the Archimedean Double Sequence](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X84901215)", *J. Math. Anal. and Applics.* **101**, 575-581

Comment: I have considered that approach and rejected it, as explained in my answer: if you apply such a criterion for $n \gt 2$, you eliminate the median as a form of mean!

Comment: Quite right - sorry, it took me a moment to see the equivalence. On a separate note, sometimes people use a standard deviation criterion for outlier exclusion before averaging (rather than a quantile criterion, as for trimmed mean). I believe this is done for some automated processes, and have seen it recommended e.g. by Andy Field for analysing reaction time data. I think such algorithms would fall foul of (5): a small change in an inlying datum may result in the exclusion of an outlying one and a discontinuity in the "mean". This is the least "strange" such generalization I can think of!

Comment: Two more desirable properties of means worth entertaining are (1) $f_{n+1}(f_n(x), x) = f_n(x)$ for all $n$ and $x$ (which is easily extended by induction); and (2) $f_{n+m}(x, \mathrm{y})$ must lie between $f_n(x)$ and $f_m(\mathrm{y})$ for all $x\in A^n, \mathrm{y}\in A^m$. The former seems very much in the spirit of Chisini. The latter may be strong enough to replace several of the weaker consistency axioms without ruling out any of the interesting means. It certainly implies axiom (1).

Answer (score 4):

One easy but fruitful generalization is to **weighted means**, $\sum_{i=1}^n w_i x_i / \sum_{i=1}^n w_i,$ where $\sum_{i=1}^n w_i = 1$. Clearly the common or garden mean is the simplest special case with equal weights $w_i = 1/n$.

Letting the weights depend on the order of values in magnitude, from smallest to largest, points to various other special cases, notably the idea of a **trimmed mean**, which is known by other names too.

To avoid excessive use of notation where it is not needed or especially helpful, imagine for example ignoring the smallest and largest values and taking the (equally weighted) mean of the others. Or imagine ignoring the two smallest and two largest and taking the mean of the others; and so forth. The most vigorous trimming would ignore all but the one or two middle values in order, depending on whether the number of values was odd or even, which is naturally just the familiar **median**. Nothing in the idea of trimming commits you to ignoring equal numbers in each tail of a sample, but saying more about asymmetric trimming would take us further away from the main idea in this thread.

In short, means (unqualified) and medians are extreme limiting cases of the family of (symmetric) trimmed means. The overall idea is to allow compromises between one ideal of using all the information in the data and another ideal of protecting oneself from extreme data points, which may be unreliable outliers.

[See the reference here](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0313) for one fairly recent review.

Answer (score 2):

I think the median can be considered a type of a generalization of the arithmetic mean.  Specifically, the arithmetic mean and the median (among others) can be unified as special cases of the [Chisini mean](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChisiniMean.html).  If you are going to perform some operation over a set of values, the Chisini mean is a number that you can substitute for all of the original values in the set and still get the same result.  For example, if you want to sum your values, replacing all the values with the arithmetic mean will yield the same sum.  The idea is that a certain value is representative of the numbers in the set in the context of a certain operation over those numbers.  (An interesting implication of this way of thinking is that a given value—the arithmetic mean—can only be considered representative under the assumption that you are doing certain things with those numbers.)

This is less obvious for the median (and I note that the median is not listed as one of the Chisini means on Wolfram or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chisini_mean)), but if you were to allow operations over ranks, the median could fit within the same idea.

Comment: This is a very interesting suggestion. Could you suggest a suitable operation, so that for a median $M$ we would have $f(M,M,...,M)=f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$?

Comment: That's a good question, @Silverfish, I've been thinking about that ;-). My thinking is more that, in your Q & the discussion in comments, the conceptual framework seems to be how to get the mean & how to get the data back from the mean; OTOH, my framing is what we use the mean for: viz as a compressed representation of the data w/ the minimum information loss.

Comment: I've added some citations to the question which show a wider range of conceptual frameworks, including this one. At the moment I can't see a better $f$ than "take the median", which doesn't quite seem within the spirit of the piece!

Comment: @Silverfish, I grant that does seem like a somewhat problematic hole in my position.

Comment: While the insight from Chisini's set-up is that, for example, the arithmetic mean preserves the sum, while the geometric mean preserves the product, it's still true (just less interesting) that the arithmetic mean of $(\bar{x}, \bar{x}, ..., \bar{x})$ is also $\bar{x}$ and so on. So I'm not convinced it's a fatal blow.

Comment: @Silverfish, yeah, that was my reasoning process as well. I was actually surprised when I went to the Wolfram page again & saw that the median wasn't listed & had no such function. I strongly suspect that there is one, but I freely admit that I can't think of any. The intuition does seem very strong to me that the median is the representative value when thinking about your data as ordinal, so it seems like there must be some rank based function.

Comment: I am suspicious that you end up having to incoporate a transformation back from ranks to the original data at some point in your construction of $f$ which is rather the line of thinking you were trying to avoid in the first place! If $f$ were a function of the ranks alone, then I can't see how $f(M,...,M)$ can be distinguished from $f(M+1,...,M+1)$ for instance.

Comment: @Silverfish, OK so it wouldn't be a rank based function then. Dunno, I still think there's probably something. Why hasn't Cardinal provided a groundbreaking answer to this question yet anyway?

Comment: You'd need ranks to find the median, so I'd only go so far as to say it isn't a function of ranks *alone* - they still underlie the calculation! Some authors *do* just use $f$ as the averaging function so taking $f$ as the median should be just fine for establishing the median as a Chisini mean, if less enlightening than hoped (I'm ignoring uniqueness issues for even $n$). See e.g. Foster, D.M.E. and  Phillips, G.M. (1984), "[A Generalization of the Archimedean Double Sequence](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X84901215)", *J. Math. Anal. and Applics.* **101**, 575-581

Answer (score -1):

The question is not well defined. If we agree on the common "street" definition of mean as the sum of n numbers divided by n then we have a stake in the ground. Further If we would look at measures of central tendency we could say both Mean and Median are generealization but not of each other. Part of my background is in non parametrics so I like the median and the robustness it provides, invariance to monotonic transformation and more. but each measure has it's place depending on objective.

Comment: Welcome to our site, Bob. I believe that if you read to the end of the question--especially the long penultimate paragraph--you will discover that it is precise and well-defined. (If not, it would be a good idea to explain what *you* mean by "not well defined.) Your comments don't really seem to address what is being asked.

Comment: I actually sympathise with Bob's feeling that the question is not terribly well-defined, in the sense that the concept of "mean" does not have a single definition, but I have tried my best to make things as clear as possible. I hope my most recent edit helps clarify things.

Comment: The reason I feel the question has some value other than mere terminology (what does mean mean anyway, and is there a definition we can stretch as far as to include the median?) is that it may be instructive to see the median as just one member of a family of generalizations of the mean; Nick Cox's example of the median as a limiting case of the trimmed mean is particularly nice - it ties in neatly with the "robustness" property you like. In the family of trimmed means, the "street" arithmetic mean and the median lie at opposite ends with a spectrum between them.